# Wake On Lan (WOL) for Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E

Tags: networking, ethernet, wakeonlan

I'm unsuccessfully trying to get Wake on Lan to work with my local server (IP Address : 192.168.0.2, distro Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS) which has a Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E ethernet card.

The computer sending the WOL is a Macbook Pro which is connected on the same network.
Yet the server fails to start.

Here what I have done so far :

```
name@serverName ~ $ cat  /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
HDEF      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PXSX      S3    *disabled  
PXSX      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
PXSX      S0    *disabled  
USB1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.1
USB3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.2
USB5      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.1
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.7
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.7

name@serverName ~ $ lspci
------
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)
------

name@serverName ~ $ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

and I'm calling the WOL with :

```
name@serverName ~ $ wakeonlan xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I have succesfully activated the WOL option in my computer BIOS.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

To start a machine via WOL the network interfaces need to be left active after shutdown.

Type

```
root@host:~# cat /etc/init.d/halt | grep ^NETDOWN
NETDOWN=yes
```

to control if they are left on.
To leave the network interfaces on set the `NETDOWN` variable in your `/etc/init.d/halt` script to:

```
NETDOWN=no
```

Comment: I updated NETDOWN to "no" but WOL is still not working. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I think you already did, but are you sure you have enabled wake on lan in Bios?

Comment: I did (and otherwise, I think ethtool would have showed something different).